# Golang: create TCP 3-way handshake using ipv4.NewRawConn

Tags: go, sockets, tcp, network-programming

I'm trying to successfully establish a TCP 3-way handshake.
I want to be able to control the IP layer, ideally with [github.com/google/gopacket](https://github.com/google/gopacket).

Here's my Go program:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net"

    "github.com/google/gopacket"
    "github.com/google/gopacket/layers"
    "golang.org/x/net/ipv4"
)

func main() {
    proto := layers.IPProtocolTCP

    c, err := net.ListenPacket(fmt.Sprintf("ip4:%d", proto), "127.0.0.1")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer c.Close()

    iprawconn, err := ipv4.NewRawConn(c)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    tcp := layers.TCP{
        SrcPort: 43124,
        DstPort: 2222,
        SYN:     true,
        ACK:     false,
        Window:  65535,
        Seq:     231,
    }
    // payload := []byte{'a', 'b', 'c', '\n'}
    options := gopacket.SerializeOptions{
        // ComputeChecksums: true,
        FixLengths: true,
    }
    buffer := gopacket.NewSerializeBuffer()
    err = gopacket.SerializeLayers(buffer, options,
        &tcp,
        // gopacket.Payload(payload),
    )
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("[-] Serialize error: %s\n", err.Error())
        return
    }
    b := buffer.Bytes()
    fmt.Println(b)

    h := &ipv4.Header{
        Version:  ipv4.Version,
        Len:      ipv4.HeaderLen,
        TotalLen: ipv4.HeaderLen + len(b),
        // ID:       12345,
        Protocol: int(proto),
        // Src:      net.ParseIP("192.168.25.1").To4(),
        Dst: net.ParseIP("127.0.0.1").To4(),
        TTL: 64,
    }

    if err := iprawconn.WriteTo(h, b, nil); err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }

    buf := make([]byte, 1024)
    for {
        _, p, _, err := iprawconn.ReadFrom(buf)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("Error reading: %#v\n", err)
            return
        }
        fmt.Printf("Message received: %s\n", string(p))
        fmt.Printf("Message received: %s\n", string(buf))
    }
}
```

I'm using `nc -vvln 2222` to listen.

Running my program it looks like `iprawconn.ReadFrom(buf)` never reads the replies (SYN+ACK) from the server.

```
➜  send_packet sudo go run main.go
Password:
[168 116 8 174 0 0 0 231 0 0 0 0 80 2 255 255 0 0 0 0]
```

With Wireshark I see that my client replies with RST:
[image]

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: How are you making sure that the host OS is not interfering with the TCP request first?